# Nginx + CarrierWave + Fog + GoogleCloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, carrierwave, fog, gcloud-ruby

I tried with solutions and answers that already exist in this environment but do not solve my problem, so I open a new thread.

Mount a test server with these technologies in a homely own server and works perfectly in keeping gcloud store. When I ride gcloud a server with the same configuration it does not work.
I discard probleamas Fog credentials proque in pre-production environment works.

user permissions and try 644 755

When I upload a photo, rather than persist in gcloud storage, it is in the root project folder with filenames such RackMultipart20160414-4440-ry1g0r.jpg

and stored in public / uploads / tmp folder one

No more can be. settings are

### config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb

```
    config.fog_credentials = {
            :provider                         => 'Google',
            :google_storage_access_key_id     => Figaro.env.google_storage_access_key_id,
            :google_storage_secret_access_key => Figaro.env.google_storage_secret_access_key
    }
    config.fog_directory = 'uploads-prod'
config.fog_public = true
config.storage = :fog
config.root = Rails.root.join('public')
```

### content_uploader.rb

def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

Any idea or solution ?!
Thank you

Comment: Do you actually have the fog_provider configured? As in `config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'`

Comment: If I do, it generates an error "undefined method` fog_provider = 'for CarrierWave :: Uploader :: Base: Class ".

My confusion is that on a local server in my office google cloud storage saved, but the server does not save google google cloud cloud storage. it's strange....

Comment: Solved!. In production not showing error description. I not installerd graphicsmagick.

Thank!